# addChildViewController don't fit UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

Inspired from [Scott Sherwood tutorial](https://github.com/scott-sherwood/Tutorials/tree/master/SSCustomTabBar) I have a UIView inside a UIViewController that charged different UItableviewController/UIViewController through custom segues.

[image]

**segue.m**

```
- (void) perform {

DashboardViewController *controller = (DashboardViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

for(UIView *view in controller.container.subviews){
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}


controller.currentViewController = dst;
[controller addChildViewController:dst];
[controller.container addSubview:dst.view];
}
```

The first segue is called in the viewDidLoad method

**controller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"dashboardNewPon" sender:[self.buttons.subviews objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

and the screen starts in this way

[image]

the other segues, have this behavior

[image]

I can not understand why, but it certainly does autolayout.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by reading this [article](https://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/ios-how-to-programmatically-add-auto-layout-constraints-for-a-view-that-will-fit-its-superview/).

After this line

```
[controller.container addSubview:dst.view];
```

I added this

```
dst.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[controller.container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dst.view
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:controller.container
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          multiplier:1.0
                                                            constant:0.0]];

[controller.container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dst.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:controller.container
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];

[controller.container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dst.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:controller.container
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];

[controller.container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dst.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:controller.container
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
```

Comment: Yes, you also need constraints. Sorry, I assumed that you already added them in interface builder.

Comment: But how do I put in interface builder the constraints that will be added after the start? Thanks!

Comment: Now I see you added constraints between dst.view and container, while I was talking about constraints between container and controller.view. I didn't need to add constraints to added subviews, but if you do, the code you provided is correct. (Anyway, I updated my answer, because I overlooked the origin of container frame.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add this line

```
CGRect dstFrame = CGRectMake (0, 0, controller.container.frame.size.width, controller.container.frame.size.height);    
dst.view.frame = dstFrame;
```

after

```
controller.currentViewController = dst;
```

And call the first segue in viewWillAppear:

Comment: The code is the same or am I wrong? viewWillAppear does not change the result